# CSS cutting off the end of the input box

Tags: html, css

For goodness sake!! Why is my input box being cut off on the right? I've looked into the padding and margins in chrome and I cant see whats causing it. I am new to this, but it remains a mystery.

http://jsfiddle.net/GCt3z/1/

Comment: you have overflow:hidden on your fieldwrapper div. Cutting off things is what overflow:hidden does.

Comment: I didn't have this problem, but I was trying to achieve what you're trying to get rid of. Thanks @Asad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it's 100% + 10px (padding) + 2px (border) wide. Try using:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
```

See the updated Fiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/GCt3z/2/

Comment: Sorry but the compatibility of this isn't sufficient for this project :(

Comment: OK, that's a shame. I assumed when I saw your CSS contained other CSS3 properties that it wasn't such a big deal. Good luck with that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`.fieldwrapper` has `overflow: hidden`. You are setting `label` as float, which means that the next div will get width of the entire wrapper. This will move it to the right of the label with with equal to the parent of the both tags. You need to set fixed width for `.fieldwrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

You input is longer than its parent which has overflow set to hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Change `.fieldwrapper` to `{ overflow: auto;}` and you can see that the input is overflowing that div.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce `width:100%` to `width:96%` in `.field` class, then the issue will be solved