# Fluid input and fixed sidebar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a 100% fluid input box with a description on the left. I had it pretty much exactly how I wanted except it is now causing me problems when I put a border on the input box because it cuts it off on the right side.

Without resorting to using 99% instead of 100% width, how can I achieve this? Should I be doing this with an extra div instead of a "label"?

http://jsfiddle.net/GCt3z/18/

Comment: Duolicate of your own question, isnt it??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885465/css-cutting-off-the-end-of-the-input-box

Comment: I felt that the question has changed since I have a better understanding of what is causing it. I also changed the code significantly since that question in order to get to the core issue. I hope this isnt a problem.

Comment: Yes but overflow:hidden remain and that is causing your problem?

Comment: When you remove it it puts it onto a new line http://jsfiddle.net/GCt3z/19/

Comment: Why dont you float the label left of the input instead?

Comment: I dont fully understand. The label is floated left already.

Comment: No. Label is floated, but input field is in the wrapper div (block) with width 100% and no float.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand. Are you saying I should float it right? If you could show me on the fiddle it would be good because I dont understand at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Will change the box-model on the element, which would include border and padding inside of the width calculation.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/QHz2z/)**

Comment: This would work but isnt very cross browser compatible. Do I have any other options?

Comment: @user1738522: It is [very cross browser compatible](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing) I can't help you with IE>8.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a padding to compensate for the border being cut off would solve your issue as easy as possible:

```
 .fieldwrapper { overflow: hidden; padding: 0 2px}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GCt3z/24/